# Crash accessing SwiftData model context from environment in a child SwiftUI view in NavigationSplitView resulting in ability to @Query successfully

Tags: swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-modelcontext

I have a `ChildView` that you can access via `NavigationLink` and that will display in a `NavigationSplitView`’s detail pane.

```
NavigationSplitView {
  ListView()
} detail: {
}
```

And

```
.navigationDestination(for: ChildModel.self) { post in
   ChildView()
}
```

`ChildView` declares an Environment property for the model context:

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
```

It also has a SwiftData `@Query` property declared to retrieve all stored DbModel objects:

```
@Query private var dbModel: [DbModel]
```

However, it always returns empty (when it is not true) and I see this warning pop:

> Set a .modelContext in view's environment to use Query

I have seen [Query() in view with model container attached shows error saying it does not have a model container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878894/query-in-view-with-model-container-attached-shows-error-saying-it-does-not-hav) which is similar but I wanted to follow up for a better understanding.

If I follow the advice in the answer above, and drop the @Query to replace with a `FetchDescription` in the `ChildView` constructor:

```
init() {
  let predicate = #Predicate<DbModel> {
    $0.id == self.id
  }
  let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<DbModel>(predicate: predicate)
  if let models = try? modelContext.fetch(descriptor) {
    /// do something here
  }
}
```

It crashes:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)

And has an accompanying warning:

> Accessing Environment's value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.

If I instead I refer to a reference of the context that I store after an app launch, it works fine:

```
if let models = try? AppController.shared.modelContextReference.fetch(descriptor) {
```

That’s progress, but I would appreciate clarification on two things:

1. How can I ensure the `ChildView` has environment access to the model context from a SwiftUI perspective, and for it to return the correct results (with no warning)? As in without needing to refer to a stored reference inside a class object.
2. I know `@Query` automatically stays up to date every time my data changes, and will reinvoke my SwiftUI view so it stays in sync. However, given I’m being forced to use a `FetchDescriptor` in the view’s constructor, does the same hold true? As in will the view — depending on a `FetchDescriptor` inside the `.init()` and not a `@Query` — also update whenever there are changes detected to the DbModel set?

The wider context is I am only interested in `DbModel` results for `ChildView` that are relevant (i.e. share the same id). So I’m also curious whether — [short of having ability to dynamically query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76530446/698971) — that this will perform similarly to a `@Query` that has a filter defined with no dynamic value check.

Comment: The first error message is probably because you don’t have a `.modelContainer` in the ChildView`s view hierarchy

Comment: The second is very explicit Environment is only for Views. I suggest going through the basic tutorials.

Comment: To be clear, I have inserted the model context into the environment both at a root level as well as attached to the problematic view itself. So it definitely isn’t this.

Comment: I know Environment is only for views. I don’t believe I suggested a misunderstanding of its application, in fact the opposite. Also, this doesn’t answer my second question (nor do any basic tutorials as it’s quite a specific ask).

Comment: Note that I said _modelContainer_, not context. About your second question, if you execute a Fetchdescriptor it will execute only once. You need to re-execute it yourself to include any new changes.

Comment: I see yes. But I have injected the container into the environment too at a root level. I have however not tried to attach it to the ChildView directly. Shouldn’t what I have done though be enough?

Comment: Thank you for clarification on FetchDescriptor. In this case, does that mean if I have a @Query which I modify in the init constructor with a dynamic filter condition, that any updates will also need to be handled manually?

Comment: Also how can one know there are changes to a specific SwiftData model to re-execute the FetchDescriptor?

Comment: If you use @Query it will work the same no matter which init you choose to use.

Comment: Sorry that isn’t clear. If I @Query for all DbModels, but inside the .init() I filter, when there are changes to @Query’s associated model, will the collection be filtered (via init FetchDescriptor) or not?

Comment: Just do it like in the last answer you linked to in your question.